# Unable to use findAll() to search sub-directories

Tags: docpad, eco

I'm using an `eco renderer` within `Docpad` (building a site based on https://github.com/zenorocha/browser-diet)

In it, I need to find all the documents in a particular sub-directory.

The directory structure is:

`/src/documents/test1/test2`

I need to find the documents stored in `test2`

I can find all the documents in `test1` using:

```
<% for item in @getCollection("documents").findAll({ url: $startsWith: '/test1'}, [order:-1]).toJSON(): %>
```

No documents are returned when I add an extra sub-directory, using:

```
<% for item in @getCollection("documents").findAll({ url: $startsWith: '/test1/test2'}, [order:-1]).toJSON(): %>
```

There are documents at that URL, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right. I just tested it in my project with the following code (tools is my generic collection defined in docpad.coffee):

```
<% for docu in @getCollection("tools").findAll(url:$startsWith:"/tools/adminui").toJSON(): %>
    <% console.log(docu.url) %>
<% end %>
```

and in the console I get only the list of urls that start with /tools/adminui.
Just try to investigate it further with console output or share more details